# Use Ckeditor like a simple input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, textinput

I need to use CKEDITOR ( http://ckeditor.com/ ) like a simple

```
<input type="text" />
```

I modified the file config.js adding the following settings:

```
config.toolbar = 'SimpleVersion';
config.toolbar_SimpleVersion =
    [
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText'],
    ];
```

Then, in the main page:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace("mydiv", { toolbar : 'SimpleVersion' });
editor.config.height = 50;
editor.config.removePlugins = 'resize';
editor.config.resize_enabled = false;
```

It works, but I need, if it's possible, to remove the bottom part where "body" is written, and also inhibit the new line whenever the Return button is pressed.

I think that for the last one, it may be possible to use a JQuery trigger.

Comment: seems like overkill using ckEditor for an input. Do you want html as value in the field? Can't you just expand size of input when needed?

Comment: It's not necessary that the value is html, I need only to store simple text, but if this is not possible I can filter the text using php before the saving in the DB.
I know that is a strange question and that I can use another light editor to make this behaviour or simply add a input text and then develop the code in jquery to Cut, Copy, Paste...but I'm using CKEDITOR with multiple instances in the same page and with different functionality. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1) when I create the editor there is a configuration option to toggle the bottom part of the editor

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace("mydiv", { toolbar : 'SimpleVersion', removePlugins : 'elementspath' });
```

2) to inhibite the return button I've created the following trigger on key:

```
editor.on('key', function(e) {
   var key = e.data.keyCode;      
       if(key==13){
          return false;
       }
}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing plugin works good. But on new line below code worked for me:

```
editor.on('key', function(e) {
    var key = e.data.keyCode;      
        if(key==13){
            e.cancel();
        }
    }
);
```